# How to compile and run a simple C program with Sublime Text 2?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I want to compile a simple C program with GCC. What do I need to put in the sublime-build file to do so?

Comment: Already figured out how to do this, but as I couldn't find a proper answer for this elsewhere (not for Mac anyways), I thought I'd post it here.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490889/build-and-run-with-arguments-in-sublime-text-2 for how to do this with dynamic arguments (see plugin InputArgs)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mac OS X:

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell":true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Windows:

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell":true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

Comment: @Michael Anthony, thanks for the heads-up re: Windows and adding ".exe"

Comment: How do you enter values at run time? I mean if we use `scanf( )`, how to enter a value for that instruction during runtime from sublime text?

Comment: In case it saves future coders some headache, I just wanted to note that you should place this in a build system config file by going to Tools > Build System > New Build System and NOT in a preferences config file (Preferences > Settings - More > Syntax Specific).

Comment: Personally, I get `clang: error: no input files` on my Mac where as running `gcc test.c -o test` in my console works.

Comment: @bafromca I get the same issue - if I modify it to look like Scott Fister's answer where the first command is a single string it seems to work: `"cmd": "gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name}"`

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer did not work for  me.

What I did is the following:

```
{
  "cmd" : ["make $file_base_name && ./$file_base_name"],
  "selector" : "source.c",
  "shell": true,
  "working_dir" : "$file_path",
}
```

Setting `shell` to `true` means it reads the `cmd` as one line, so I call make to compile and then run the script. The other option is to have `shell` set to `false` but you're unable to run multiple `cmd`. So the only way I got it to work was have it make the file with `CMD + B` and then run it with `CMD + Shift + B`:

```
{
  "cmd" : ["make", "$file_base_name"],
  "selector" : "source.c",
  "shell": false,
  "working_dir" : "$file_path",

  "variants": [
    {
      "cmd" : ["./$file_base_name"],
      "name": "Run"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, compile and run, with file_regex

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "file_regex": "^([^:]+):([0-9]+):",
    "selector": "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mac

```
{
"cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to activate do script \"clear&&${file_path}/${file_base_name} && read -p \\\"Press Enter to exit.\\\"&&exit\"'"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"selector": "source.c, source.c++",

"variants":
[
    {
        "name": "Run",
        "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
    }
]
```

}

For windows

```
{
"cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o","${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
"file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:?(.*)$",
"working_dir": "${file_path}",
"encoding":"cp936",
"selector": "source.c",
"variants":
[
    {
    "name": "Run",
    "cmd": ["cmd","/C","start","cmd","/c", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe &pause"]
    }
]
}
```

**The configuration files above make you input data in the terminal(Mac) or cmd(windows),the output also was shown in the terminal or cmd。**

Answer (score 0):

LINUX! COMPILING AND RUNNING IN TERMINAL, LANGUAGE C
Create a new Build System and paste this code:

```
{
"cmd": ["xterm-256color -e 'zsh -c \"gcc $file_name -o ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name} ;echo;echo Presiona ENTER para salir...; read line\"'"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell": true
}
```

> echo $SHELL = To know which shell you use (zsh)-------------------------------------------------------------echo $TERM = To know which terminal you use (xterm-256color)-------------------------------------------

:D