# How to run a C program in Sublime Text 2

Tags: c, sublimetext2

In this question I learned how to use Sublime Text 2 to compile a C program:

[How to compile and run a simple C program with Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059511/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-c-program-with-sublime-text-2)

How do I also make the program run from within Sublime Text 2?

Comment: I didnt downvote, but whats wrong with running a shell in a separate window and pressing up, enter? Either way its probably got something to do with your PATH/compiler.

Comment: This might be of use: http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-run-C-code-from-inside-Sublime-Text-2

Answer (score 3):

Edit your build file to add the command that runs the program. You can see the output of the program in the ST console by hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>.

```
    {
      "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file_name", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
      "selector" : "source.c",
      "shell" : true,
      "working_dir" : "$file_path"
    }
```

As an alternative, you could make a shell script or Makefile that compiles and runs the file and then call the script or make from the ST build command.