# Build and run with arguments in Sublime Text 2

Tags: build, parameter-passing, sublimetext2

I'm running on MacOS X and I'm using Sublime Text 2 to code.

I've found the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> option to build and <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to build and run.

Is it possible to run a program (or script) and pass arguments. Exemple:

```
myProg arg1 arg2
```

Note: I'm using multiple languages (C++, Java, Python), so I hope there is a way to set the arguments for each project and not for all build.

**Edit**

I want to set the parameters for a program call, a little bit like in eclipse where you can set the arguments when you run your program.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For each project you can create a `.sublime-project` file with your specific `build_system` on it:

```json
{
  "folders":
  [{
    "path": "src"
  }],
  "build_systems":
  [{
    "name": "Run with args",
    "cmd": ["python", "$file", "some", "args"]
  }]
}
```

This way you don't pollute the global Build System menu and won't have to worry about switching build system as you switch projects. This file is also easy to access when you need to change the arguments:

```json
Cmd-Shift-P > Edit Project
```

Comment: buddy if we need to pass dynamic argument every time then what would be the best possible way to get it done....?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? You have full access to a shell here, you can store your "dynamic" thing in a file, and read it statically in the sublime build.

Comment: for instance you want to run nodejs npm installer for underscore then you will write command as in "npm install underscore" but next time you want to load express then you will write command as in "npm install express". So my doubt it do we have provision through keyboard to select arg and use it to load node modules same as we have for finding text in file e.g. : select any text in file then ctrl+F. You will find it in find panel.

Answer (score 19):

[InputArgs](https://github.com/bilalba/InputArgs) does precisely what you're looking for. It shows an input dialog **every time** you run build(ctrl+b) and you can supply it with space separated arguments from within sublime text.

Comment: Does what everyone would expect to do when u do ctrl+shit+b and the dialog opens. It is perfect and handles history of commands supplied (push up). Thank you so much.

Comment: I just tried this with a node.js build system, and if I pass a series of parameters separated by spaces, I get them as one big parameter:

ie. if I want to simulate `node program.js 1 2 3`, what I get when I enter `1 2 3` in the dialog is a single string `1 2 3` rather than 3 separate string parameters.

Answer (score 9):

I found a simple solution is create a python file in the same directory:

```
import os
os.system("python filename.py some args")
```

Comment: That will be my fallback option (not always under sublime), but need some tweaks like check for os.argv and maybe, using raw_input to ask for many args, then launching with os.execv() instead os.system().

Comment: This is tricky and simple way to run your python script with parameters. This advice had very help me, thanks.