# how to pass dynamic argument in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

for eg : if I want to install npm package through keyboard shortcut in sublime text by selecting the text then every time the argument will be the one that I selected(using mouse/keyboard) before using keyboard shortcut to trigger.

Comment: You'll need to write a [plugin](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [sublime-text-shell-command](https://github.com/markbirbeck/sublime-text-shell-command) plugin. According to the documentation, the following should do exactly what you want:

```
[
  {
    "keys": ["ctrl+enter"],
    "command": "shell_command",
    "args": {
      "command": "npm install",
      "region": "arg"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The previous question to that already had a valid plugin that works. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618240/how-to-pass-paramaters-to-a-build-in-sublime-text-3