# Compile cython code with "python compile.py" and no "build" command-line parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, distutils

I have a compile.py script:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize("module1.pyx"))
```

that compiles my Cython code. The drawback is that I have to call it with a command-line parameter `build`:

```
python compile.py build
```

Instead, I would like to be able to call this `compile.py` directly from Sublime Text, as usual, with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. To do that, it should work from:

```
python compile.py
```

**Question: how to modify the above script so that it can be run with `python compile.py`?**

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490889/build-and-run-with-arguments-in-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Method #1**:

  Use `script_args` like this:

  ```
  setup(ext_modules=cythonize("module1.pyx", build_dir="build"), script_args=['build'])
  ```

  or

  ```
  setup(ext_modules=cythonize("module1.pyx", build_dir="build"), script_args=['build_ext'])
  ```

  (both work).

  If you want the output files to be in the same directory, you can use:

  ```
  setup(ext_modules=cythonize("module1.pyx", build_dir="build"), script_args=['build'], 
                                              options={'build':{'build_lib':'.'}})
  ```

  or

  ```
  setup(ext_modules=cythonize("module1.pyx", build_dir="build"), script_args=['build_ext'],
                                              options={'build_ext':{'inplace':True}})
  ```
- **Method #2**:

  Add this on top:

  ```
   import sys; sys.argv = ["", "build"]
  ```

  It's a bit hack-ish but it works fine, and avoids to have to create a new build-system, like with [Build and run with arguments in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18512505/1422096) (link kindly provided by @Melvin).