# "error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" when compiling Cython code

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++, cython, distutils

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat), I have succesfully installed [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) to compile some Cython code, but:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
setup(ext_modules = cythonize("module1.pyx"))
```

still produces:

> error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

**How to compile Cython code with Python 2.7 (for example on Windows 7 x64)?**

*Note: I already carefully read the question [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) but the main answers (including modifying `msvc9compiler.py`) didn't solve it.*

Comment: @NewEnglandcottontail: doesn't `python -m pip install --upgrade setuptools` solve your question? also what's the *VStudio* version you have installed?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I spent hours on this, and the information was not easily findable in [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat), that's why I post it here with the "answer your own question" feature:

- Step 1: Install [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)
- Remark: You **don't** need to modify `msvc9compiler.py` as often suggested in many forum posts
- Step 2: Just add `import setuptools` that will help Python and "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7" work together.

  ```
  import setuptools  # important
  from distutils.core import setup
  from Cython.Build import cythonize
  setup(ext_modules=cythonize("module1.pyx", build_dir="build"),
                                             script_args=['build'], 
                                             options={'build':{'build_lib':'.'}})
  ```

  Note: the `script_args` parameter allows to run this setup.py with just `python setup.py` (i.e. CTRL+B in your favorite editor like Sublime Text) [instead of having to pass command-line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53171841/compile-cython-code-with-python-compile-py-and-no-build-command-line-paramet) like this: `python setup.py build`.

It works!

Comment: just adding "import setuptools" made the error disappear

Comment: The link in step 1 is not available anymore :(

Answer (score 8):

**Python >= 3.5**

I wanted to comment on @Basj (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53172602/6596203) answer but I couldn't so I apologize. I just want to add to @Basj answer for people using Python >= 3.5, instead of Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7, you can install just the C++ in this installer [Build Tool for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16) or you can simply install that with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2019-workload-vctools).

Comment: The link for 'Build Tool for Visual Studio 2019' leads me to download the whole Visual Studio. Is this intended?

Comment: @Idonknow, yes, the download link for Build Tool for Visual Studio is the whole Visual Studio but during the installation process, you can choose which package to install. I would suggest Chocolatey as it is much easier!

Comment: what if your installation is within a virtual enviroment?

Comment: Good question, I don't think i have the answer for that. I guess you still have to install the C++ compiler on the whole system?!

Comment: the installer of visual studio, asks for 6.46GB to install the C++ build tools !!!

Comment: @Yehdhih ANNA that is why I suggest the chocolatey as in my answer above as well as my reply to Idonknow's question above!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that fixed it for me.  Use Git Bash and use the following:

```
INCLUDE="C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22621.0/ucrt/;C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22621.0/shared/" \
> LIB="C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/ucrt/x64;C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.22621.0/um/x64" \
> PATH=$PATH:/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ Kits/10/bin/10.0.22621.0/x64 \
> python -m pip install <package>
```

Then run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Git Bash will detect visual Studio Cmd, Anaconda do not.  I am running Microsoft Visual Studio 2022, Microsoft Visual Studio Tools and Microsoft Visual 2017 v 14.00

Theoretical solutions I tried that didn't help me but others said it work below:

The same reason this issue is present these days is because Microsoft made it.  Likely a pathing issue and issue is reappearing which is Microsoft specialty since 2018.

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3329

This might fix for you but again this is Microsoft:

```
import setuptools  # as requested
import distutils._msvccompiler
```

You can also change/check regedit:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.2\Setup\VC]
"ProductDir"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\VC]
"ProductDir"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Auxiliary\\Build"
```

Another option is to check the correct environment variables as well as delete any and all visual Studio stuff you do not need/use.

environment variable path and delete old ones and restart pc afterwards:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64_arm
    C:\Users\AAAAA\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64
```

Use Anaconda and use the following:

```
    SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/419525/microsoft-visual-c-140-or-greater-is-required.html
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248425/discussion-on-answer-by-cave-johnson123-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-wh).