# How to replace multiplication and sum in np.dot with other elementwise and reduce operation respectively

Tags: arrays, performance, numpy

Let's say you have 2 relatively large arrays `a` and `b`. You could use broadcasting to do a `dot` product:

```
a = np.random.normal(size=(1000, 300))
b = a*2

ref = a.dot(b.T)
res = (a[:,None,:]*b[None,:,:]).sum(2)
np.allclose(ref, res)
# True

timeit -n 1 -r 5 a.dot(b.T)
# 17.6 ms    
timeit -n 1 -r 5 (a[:,None,:]*b[None,:,:]).sum(2)
# 1.83 s
```

Performance difference is roughly 2 orders of magnitude, even larger for bigger arrays.
`np.dot` is much faster because it uses specialized libraries, but also because it does not store in memory the full temporal array `a[:,None,:]*b[None,:,:]`

`np.dot` always does a multiplication and then a sum-reduction. I wonder if it would be possible to replace the multiplication operation by any other elementwise operatio (like `np.maximum`, `==`, `np.power`...) and the sum-reduction by other reduction operation like `np.max`. I know this would have niche real-world applications, but I think it could be useful in some cases.

I have tried using `numexpr`, but it has limited support for funcs and dtypes.

I have also tried creating an array with `dype=object`, with custom multiplication and sum methods, but then you are not dealing with contiguous chunks of memory anymore.

Is there any effective way to accomplish this in numpy?

Ideally some function whith synthax: `np.custom_dot(a,b, elementwise_func=my_func, redux_func=my_other_func)`

Comment: can't you write your own specialized library? Maybe in cython for a start.

Comment: @hpaulj I have used cython a couple of times for simple things (and often times I get this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172601/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-compiling-cython-code)). I was hoping for a simpler pure `numpy` solution

Comment: This sounds like something that numba (https://github.com/numba/numba) would be perfect for.

Comment: The original `np.einsum` (now embodied in the `c_einsum` function) used cython and `nditer` to perform the sum of products on a complex combination of dimensions.  I dug into this years ago when I wrote a patch for the use of ellipsis.  At the time there was also a issue request for `einsum` that could use other pairs of operators.  The `np.nditer` doesn't help with performance, but as shown on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html can be a stepping stone toward using it in cython.

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,kj',a,b, optimize=True)` gives the same timings as your dot.  `np.einsum('ij,kj',a,b, optimize=False)`  uses the original (nditer) version

Comment: "np.dot always does a multiplication and then a sum-reduction" At first make sure, that you know how a matrix multiplication is usually implemented.  eg. https://gist.github.com/nadavrot/5b35d44e8ba3dd718e595e40184d03f0 How far do you want to go (Register Blocking,Tilling,...)?

Comment: @max9111 That link is pretty interesting. I don't want to go very far, I was hoping for a simple numpy solution. I may do something with cython in the future.