# Pythran cannot find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, pythran

I installed the Python library Pythran on a Windows machine using 'pip install pythran', and got no error. But when trying to compile a function using 'pythran functionName.py' I get the following result:

pythran functionName.py
WARNING: Failed to find 'pythran-openblas' package. Please install it or change the compiler.blas setting. Defaulting to 'blas'
WARNING: Compilation error, trying hard to find its origin...
WARNING: Nop, I'm going to flood you with C++ errors!
CRITICAL: Cover me Jack. Jack? Jaaaaack!!!!
E: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

First question: how can I install pythran-openblas
Second question: I have vcvarsall.bat on my machine in the folder C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0, where is Pythran looking for vcvarsall?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the `vcvarsall.bat` issue, you can have a look at ["error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" when compiling Cython code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172601/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-when-compiling-cython-code?rq=1) choosing the first or second answer depending on the Pytho version you're using. basically, you need to install the right Visual Studio package to make that file available.

Concerning `pythran-openblas`, it should be available through `pip`: https://pypi.org/project/pythran-openblas