# Basic C programming_while_runtime error

Tags: c

As a beginner I learn programming currently with Sublime Text on OSX.
The code attached is compiled via Sublime Text.
The runtime error is, when I input any non-integer data such as 'a' or '9.3', the while-loop will not break.

*Below is the instruction of work: 
Test a program with only a main() function that repeatedly: 
1. requests the user to enter an integer, 
2. reads an integer, 
3. processes the integer as follows: returns to terminate the program for 0, prints "one" for 1, prints "two" for 2, prints "I don't know that" for any other integer. 

e.g. the following is a possible sequence that might appear at the terminal, where the integers are entered by the user: 
Please enter an integer 
2 
two 
Please enter an integer 
33 
I don't know that 
Please enter an integer 
1 
one Please enter an integer 
0*

## Below is my code.

## Thanks for help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int n;
    int a = 1;

    while (a!=0){
        printf("Please enter an integer\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n == 1) printf("one\n");
        else if (n==2) printf("two\n");
        else if (n==0) return 0;
        else if (n<0 || n >2) printf("I don't know that\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add `else break;`?

Comment: Hello World does work. I referred to this link the other day.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059511/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-c-program-with-sublime-text-2

Comment: Works fine on my machine (GNU GCC compiler).

Comment: @green_claws Then `else a=0;` should also do it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That indeed is one solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Shomz mine shows 'i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int looper = 1;
    while(looper){
        printf("Please enter an integer:\n");
        int i;
        scanf("%d", &i);
        if(i==0){
            looper = 0;
        }
        else if(i==1){
            printf("one\n");

        }
        else if(i==2){
            printf("two\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("I don't know that\n");
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `terminator` is a poor name for a variable that tells the loop *not* to terminate. `terminator = 0;` would be much clearer than `terminator -= 1;`.

Comment: Fair enough! Thumbs up and I've modified this piece.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop never terminates because you never tell it to terminate. It continues to execute as long as `a != 0`. You initialize `a` to 1 and you never change it, so naturally you have an infinite loop.

You're also not checking whether `scanf` succeeded. If you enter some garbage value, it will leave `n` with its previous value and return a result indicating that it failed to read a new value, but your program doesn't distinguish between success and failure.

`scanf` returns an `int` result indicating how many items it was able to read (or `EOF`, a negative value, if there was an error). You should at least compare the value to `1` to see whether it succeeded.

It appears that you intend to use `a` to determine whether the loop should continue executing. You should give it a more meaningful name, like `keep_going`. And you can make it a `bool` (if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`, if your compiler supports it), but using an `int` with `0` for false and `1` for true is also ok.

```
int keep_going = 1;
while (keep_going) {
    /* ... */
    if (...) {
        keep_going = 0;
    }
}
```

Or you can write an infinite loop and use `break` to terminate it:

```
while (1) {
    /* ... */
    if (...) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In C language, how to make scanf tell the type of data input, integer, float or char?

Comment: You need to read the documentation for `scanf`, either by running `man scanf` if your system has man pages) or by [finding it on the web](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). `scanf` format strings are similar (but not identical) to `printf` format strings; they're effectively small programs in a tiny special-purpose language.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `if` `else`, I would suggest using a `switch` statement

If you need to use only `if` `else`, then include another `else` statement mentioning.

```
else
    exit(0);
```

for your program to terminate in such a case.

Comment: That is one solution.

Comment: Please don't use silly abbreviations like "u" and "ur". Spelling out the words "you" and "your" makes your answer much easier to read.