# How to compile and run C in sublime text 2 without creating an exe file

Tags: c, sublimetext2

How can I compile and run C in sublime text 2 without creating an executable file on build?

Comment: Make a script that compiles the code, runs it, and then immediately deletes the executable. Same result - probably much easier (especially if you want to use a normal C compilter)!

Comment: You can't - C is a *compiled* language. Unless you're building a library, in which case you don't run it anyway, you need to compile a C program before running it.

Comment: Let me guess, you're on a school computer or something that prohibits running untrusted EXE files?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can't. C is a compiled language. When you compile it, it produces an `exe`, or an `out` file, which you run.

If you're still confused, see: [How to compile and run a simple C program with Sublime Text 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059511/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-c-program-with-sublime-text-2)

Also see [this](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-program-execution/).

[image]